# Vue 3 suspense: fetch data again and go back to "loading" state

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Using Vue 3 suspense, I manage to show a loading state when my async component is loading.

Is there a way to show this loading state again when my component props get updated and I refetch data from the server, without using v-ifs (because it kind of kills the purpose of using suspense?).

Thank you!

Comment: The `Suspense` is only meant for loading the component definition, not for prop updates.